# From SQL to Rails Active Record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I have this SQL query into Rails ActiveRecord?

SELECT objects.*, (objects.value)->>0
FROM "users", jsonb_each(hit->'opportunity') objects WHERE objects.key::text ~ '^[0-9]{0,4}_pct$' and ((objects.value)->>0)::numeric >= 0.5

Comment: That looks like only half of the query and we are missing any sort of attempt to actually solve the question on your own as well as any information about the schema, models and what the actual expected result is supposed to be. https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Sorry, it's not a half of the query. It is a functional query that I use. I just dont to know how can I put it into a ActiveRecord query.

Comment: Yes, but what have you attempted and what do you actually want to do with the results? Its very unclear how you expect whatever the result is to map to your model. You're most likely going to have to use strings for most of this query as you're using a bunch of Postgres specific features.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that:

```
User.select("REPLACE(objects.key, '_pct', '' )::int AS key")
    .joins("inner join jsonb_each(users.hit->'opportunity') AS objects ON true")
    .where("objects.key::text ~ '^[0-9]{0,4}_pct$' AND ((objects.value)->>0)::numeric >= 0.5")
```